# PYTHONPATH extension?

Tags: python, add-on

I am trying to write some scripts to test blender.  I have developed some helper tasks that I would like to use from a common module.  However when I move the task from the working script into a different file and try and get the script to import from the second file it does not work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\blender-addons\test\test_import_obj.py", line 14, in <module>
    import test_helper
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_helper'
```

So I figured that I needed to at least set the PYTHONPATH to the current directory.  However when I do that then the blender bit stops working

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\blender-addons\test\test_import_obj.py", line 214, in <module>
    main(infile, module)
  File "E:\blender-addons\test\test_helper.py", line 22, in copy_plugin
    bpy.ops.wm.addon_install(overwrite=True, filepath=zfile)
NameError: name 'bpy' is not defined
```

I am using windows to develop my scripts.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please [read the docs on blender paths](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html)  Eg put your test helper module in `USER/scripts/modules/` folder and it can be imported  with `import test_helper`

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to copy the files over to the install, they are test files for testing

Comment: Please read the docs. The USER path is outside the install path.

Comment: @batFINGER So how are multi-file add-ons normally developed? You have to develop inside the `scripts/addons` folder?

Comment: @RayMairlot on linux for instance I  develop addons in my user folder `/home/batfinger/.config/blender/2.80/scripts/addons/test_addon/__init__.py`  I can re-install blender without fear of that user folder being touched.  In reality `test_addon/` is symbolically linked from elsewhere, but for all extents and purposes is in my user addons folder. Reload addon scripts using F8 shortcut to `bpy.ops.script.reload()`.    Crunch `bpy.utils.script_paths('addons')` into the python console and it returns a list of locations where blender expects to find addons.

Comment: OK copied file over to C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\modules, it seems to pick up the file for import but then I get the second error about not being able to find bpy

Comment: The second error looks like you are missing `import bpy`.  Little confused by _"I am using windows to develop my scripts."_  Unless you have built blender as a python module and installed in your system python, `bpy` is only available to scripts run from within blender.

Comment: I am calling blender from a prompt: blender --background --python "D:\storage\3D\import_obj\import_obj.py"

Comment: Gah that was it! I also forgot to import bpy into my file.

Comment: And as a result of that, you can set PYTHONPATH to the local directory and it will run, you don't have to copy it over.

Comment: I consider a script called via [srtarting blender from CLI](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options)  "running from within blender".

Answer (score 2):

Don't set `PYTHONPATH`, but rather add your script's path to `sys.path`. You can do that manually in Blender's Python Console, in a script you embed in a blend file via Blender's Text Editor, or in a small add-on that you place in a path that's already searched for by Blender.

Non-scripting approaches would be to [set an alternative scripts folder](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/file.html) in the user preferences, or to use [symlinks](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+symlink) to make Blender find your code.